# Single line command to multiply from a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file

As the title suggest, but is it possible to multiply two numbers together by reading in from a file using arithmetic expansion using only the commands `echo` or `cat`? i know you can do this through piping with the use of `bc` but i was looking to do something a little different. So say we have a text file

**Text File**

```
12*9
2*3
```

and using `cat multiply.txt | bc` but changing it so that it doesnt require the use of `bc` but instead reads in the file and does the math on its own without the use of `bc` and with the use of arithmetic expansion instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this (later learned [it's not the right way](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), read comments below)

```
for a in $(cat test.txt); do echo "$(($a))" ; done
```

Result:

```
108
6
```

With only `cat` and `echo` it could be done like this but the number of lines in the file should be known beforehand and the array creation could fail for the same reason the `for` could.

```
a=( $(cat test.txt) ); echo "$((${a[0]}))" ; echo "$((${a[1]}))"

108
6
```

Comment: Didnt think of using a for loop outside of a shell script but that works. Are there other ways that are possible without the use of the for loop though? One just using ONLY cat/echo and arithmetic expansions in one line?

Comment: To illustrate why `for` is the wrong way to do this, consider what will happen with the formula "12 * 9". It'll be split into three separate items, "12", "*", and "9"; then it'll expand the "*" to a list of files in the current directory. Try it, I dare you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `cat` either

```
for a in $(< test.txt); do echo "$(($a))" ; done
```

or

```
while read -r a; do echo "$(($a))"; done < test.txt
```

which would handle better spaces and other chars in the file

Comment: While this does the job correctly my question was to be able to do this with ONLY using cat or echo and i was wondering now if it could be done without the use of for or while loops.